# Linphone - Only default sound device available?

Tags: sound, voip, oss-sound-system

First of al.. Linphone is the first (and only) VOIP client i found so far that is free.. looks decent AND most importand: it doesn't crash (ekiga - crashes randomly lol).

I use softphone for business (duo to me being in china and the phone number from Europe.. it kind of requires Internet if you want to do it cheap).

Linphone works perfect BUT has one little glitch:
**It doesn't pick up on Sound devices.. it just shows Default alsa and default OSS.**

In total what i want to achieve is - 
**1) Ring device on speakers 

2) Microphone & Output sound on Headset.**

Ubuntu it self sees them all perfectly fine in Sound Settings..

Anyone any ideas on this?
I saw something about linphone using soundlist.. but that command doesn't exist in ubuntu?

Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Ekiga, it works great and is in the Software Center. You can skip adding their SIP service. Ekiga has options for all the things you want , where you can decide what outputs the ring, the sound, etc.

Comment: hello, and thanks for that advice.. i tried ekiga before i tried linphone. Ekiga works alright BUT the problem is it actually crashes randomly on minimizing it can dissapear from time to time or just vanish while minimized...

Comment: What version of Ekiga are you using?  Another softphone to try is Jitsi (http://jitsi.org/). It does a little more than you are looking for, as it's also a multi-chta client..but it's more full featured than most. The guys who built it are VoIP guys

Comment: Jitsi looks good.. i rather have too much functions then too less haha :) as far as ekiga.. i am not sure.. i installed it using ubuntu repo and that must of been about 2 - 3 months ago.